# Library function for computation of Julian Day number?

Tags: c, time

Is there a standard library function for computation of Julian Day number?

I see various offhand pieces of code to compute the day number and have used such code in the past. However, before I start adding more custom routines, I want to check if there is a standard library function in C to do this.

I see no such function in time.h

Comment: How about the `localtime` function?

Comment: @CraigEstey - That is Georgian calendar

Comment: The `tm_yday` of `struct tm` is, IIRC, the julian day of the year. But, I don't know of a standard library function for what you need. Since julian day/date is used in astronomy, an astronomy library might have one. So, you may have to roll your own. The wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day has various formulas for calculating to/from gregorian calendar date that are easy to cut-and-paste into a C function